# Как компилятор golang перебрасывает значение переменной в кучу?

Tags: golang, компиляция, стек, куча

Прочитал статью на хабре
[Языковая механика escape analysis](https://habr.com/ru/post/497994/)

но так и не понял один момент

Когда компилятор компилирует проблему он должен переписывает вместо переменных адреса в памяти.

Например вместо первой переменной ставит адрес 0000 вместо второй 0008 (если первая занимает 8 байт) это что касается стека

Но поидеи адреса в куче выделяются ОС во время выполнения программы, как тогда компилятор на стадии компиляции может знать по какому адресу в куче он разместит переменную?

И будут ли переменные которые он решил перекинуть в кучу уже на стадии компиляции заменяны адресами или там будет какой то механизм по типу указателей, но только на каком то внутреннем уровне, а для программиста они так и останутся переменными?

Пример из видео.
Мы вызываем функцию и внутри нее создаем переменную ссылку на которую потом возвращаем. Если переменная создастся в стеке функции answer когда мы из нее выйдем она фактически станет невалидная и может быть затерта чем то еще, поэтому логично что под переменную х выделяется адрес в куче

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMZpH4yT7M0

[image: Перемещение в кучу]

Comment: Думаю, Вам нужно немного на си пописать, тогда некоторые моменты станут на место. Но по поводу адресов - а если адреса относительные, то Ваше непонимание решается? ( Хотя в тексте немного каша)

Comment: Относительно адресного пространства ?

Comment: относительно некого начального адреса. Надо посмотреть как то, как в Go оно сделано детально, но есть подозрение, что по классике, с дескрипторами (а иначе сложно делать нормально GC)

Comment: т.е. это некий "объект" гарбедж коллектора, который фиксирует у себя все создаваемые для кучи переменные. В таком случае мы при компиляции выдаем им получается фактически фиктивные адреса, а в момент выполнения мы все таки реально запрашиваем у ОС и по сути через дескрипторы всегда общаемся с этой переменной? Самое главное что я хочу понять пока что, в бинарнике у меня на этом месте не будет стоять реального адреса (виртуальной памяти) или все таки будет?

Comment: Добавил картинку к посту и ссылку на видео

Comment: У Вас не будет реальных адресов. Представьте себе, что читается файл, строка за строкой. Кол-во объектов неизвестно, как адреса выдать (да и "дескрипторы").

Comment: Т.е. в языках где есть GC общение с переменными в куче идёт через дискрипторы (понятно что зависит от конкретной реализации но в целом так?) , а где про это написано должно быть в статьях по реализациях языков или по ос, я искал инфу но толком не нашёл ?

Comment: В принципе адрес переменной тоже может быть дескриптором. Просто сделать в таком случае "уплотнение памяти" сильно сложнее. Но в общем случае компилятор вставляет инструкцию к менеджеру памяти - создай объект и верни его адрес/дескриптор. И все.